# Configurar Delphi Berlin para api 16 ou 17 ou 18 (versão jelly bean do android)

Tags: delphi

Boa Noite,

Se alguem puder dar um help.
   Gostaria de saber se alguem tem algum tutorial para configurar o sdk android no delphi berlin para compilar nas api 16 ou 17 ou 18 (que corresponde as versões jelly bean do android).

Grato,
Cassiano

Answer (score 1):

Veja esse [**fórum**](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sdk-android-instalacao-configuracao-do-sdk-e-avd/22241) lá explica como configurar o *SDK* do ***Android*** no **Delphi**.

No [**site da Embarcadero**](https://www.embarcadero.com/starthere/xe7/mobdevsetup/android/en/installing_the_android_development_tools.html) também diz como configurar, mas está em inglês.

Também tem esse [**vídeo no YouTube**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZOxjt_IY7E) que mostra como configurar.

Basta escolher a **versão** que desejar e configurar.

Comment: Boa Tarde, Eduardo

Comment: diga em que posso ajudar?

Comment: configurei conforme o video para api 17 e 18, mas no emulador não roda da um erro e fecha. o problema é para configurar para a api 17 e 18, a partir da api 19 funciona. Alguma luz no fim do tuneu ?

Comment: Rapaz... Eu nunca usei emulador por que aqui fica muito lento... mais creio que se funcionar para o 19 vai funcionar no 17 e 18

Comment: eu utilizo a API 26 mais testo em uma Jelly bean 4.1.2 e funciona

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.... vou testar a 26 .....

Comment: marca como respondido se possível...